# Am I able to utilize Sharepoint dll if I don't own the sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We have a large sharepoint that we are manually creating sharepoint pages with templates within the main SharePoint.  This is extremely time consuming and was wondering if we could utilize the SharePoint dll so that we could create an application to programatically create sharepoints with templates, along with updating the lists and such within those newly created sharepoints.  I do not have access to the sharepoint foundations, nor would I be able to.

Would there be any access issues with me snagging a dll of this off the internet and creating sharepoints programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download what you need from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21786